# Selling Partner API Feeds API

Tags: amazon-mws

I am using the Feeds API to update inventory using the [this link](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/use-case-guides/feeds-api-use-case-guide-2020-09-04.md#step-2-encrypt-and-upload-the-feed-data). I am able to perform the Step 1 :- Create a feed document response is

```json
{
 "payload":{"encryptionDetails":
 {
  "standard":"AES","initializationVector":"vHLW3sNN41sEQp1e9wjNSg==",
  "key":"oQvgdrwiBbBO3SLf4p81zQuIgROkTDA9Yikv6DvMIcg="
},
"feedDocumentId":"amzn1.tortuga.3.11ef10ee-e839-4a0b-b7a4-dcfbe78900ae.T1OWK0QMT4NDF7",
"url":"https://tortuga-prod-eu.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/%2FNinetyDays/amzn1.tortuga.3.11ef10ee-e839-4a0b-b7a4-dcfbe78900ae.T1OWK0QMT4NDF7?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210117T190852Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=&X-Amz-Signature="
  }
}
```

At Step 2 Encrypt and upload the feed data Response :-

```
SignatureDoesNotMatch
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXAWS4-HMAC-SHA256 20210117T190852Z 20210117/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request 6efdf3105b88a49723fed6068792a6f1a5858196f957e3a52f76e4cee2ccb07e9197ea9212ce444f640080a3df1d628de0bc26d9a0cafea9577fd23d2c1b3fc6 BYTESPUT //NinetyDays/amzn1.tortuga.3.11ef10ee-e839-4a0b-b7a4-dcfbe78900ae.T1OWK0QMT4NDF7 X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=CREDENTIAL&X-Amz-Date=20210117T190852Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=content-type%3Bhost content-type:application/json host:tortuga-prod-eu.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com content-type;host UNSIGNED-PAYLOADBYTESEA417EC74F012746CpSqzu64eIWZv0Y7JWoylN5rrCAJzort9+7EGhH0KqaSHknlV+ZYuX76zqv2shr+yFDksDntFNI=
```

Anybody facing the same problem or any ideas where the problem is

Comment: Hi, can you show me how does first request looks like for you. I'm having difficulties with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65842779/amazon-seller-central-sp-api-create-a-feed-document-invalidinput
After that hope we'll be on a same page so I could check how it will go on second step. Tnx!