# Amazon Seller Central - SP-API - Create a feed document - InvalidInput

Tags: python, amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

Trying to create feed document ([here](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/use-case-guides/feeds-api-use-case-guide-2020-09-04.md#step-1-create-a-feed-document) ) and I'm getting `InvalidInput` error code.
Authentication works well (I tried other endpoints and it works) so I think headers are not the issue.

Here is my sample code:

```
endpoint = 'https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/feeds/2020-09-04/documents'
body = {
    "contentType": "text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8"
}
resp = requests.post(
    endpoint,
    auth=self.amazon_auth.auth, 
    headers=self.amazon_auth.headers,
    json=body
)
return resp
```

Response code:

```
{'errors': [{'code': 'InvalidInput',
   'message': 'Invalid Input',
   'details': ''}]}
```

I was also trying to use different `contentType` and charset (like `text/plain`) but I receive same error code!

This is first step of [Submit feed tutorial](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/use-case-guides/feeds-api-use-case-guide-2020-09-04.md#tutorial-submit-a-feed).

I'm trying to create feed so I can get `cartonIds` to download labels for a shipment I created over Amazon Seller Central.

Any hint, help is more than welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Did you get any solution of this?

Comment: Hi, I didn't, spent too much time for it - probably will pick up this topic again dep on development priority. For now we're parsing export csv files and doing the work.
Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by:

```py
requests.post(data=json.dumps(body))
```

Also make sure you pass the body for signing as well

Answer (score 0):

I use RestSharp
restRequest1.AddParameter(....); gave me the same error as yours Invalid Input
but the below line gave me a response value
restRequest1.AddJsonBody(new { contentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" });
It serializes obj to json format and adds it to the request body.

Comment: Can you show me how your request looks like, print me like all headers, body and url? I also tried with text/xml but same response. I'm using python  and you use C#?

Comment: Type :-  RequestBody
{application/json={"contentType":"text/xml; charset=UTF-8"}} 

Type :- httpHeader
{x-amz-access-token=Atza|XXXXX...}
{x-amz-security-token=XXXXXXX}
{X-Amz-Date=20210120T205817Z}
{host=sellingpartnerapi-XXXXX.amazon.com}
{Authorization=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=/20210120/XXXXX-west-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-access-token;x-amz-date;x-amz-security-token, Signature=XXX}

Comment: I dont think the problem here is the content type but how its saved in the RequestBody as u can see for me its an application/json

Comment: @JJohn I am getting below error with this way
`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details`

Answer (score -1):

This code snippet in C# worked for me, i successfully uploaded a feed

My upload method:

```
private static bool UploadFile(byte[] encrypted, string url)
{
    bool isUploaded = false;

    var contentType = "text/tab-separated-values; charset=UTF-8";

    var parameter = new Parameter
    {
        Name = contentType,
        Value = encrypted,
        Type = ParameterType.RequestBody
    };

    var restRequest = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
    restRequest.Parameters.Add(parameter);

    var restClient = new RestClient(url);
    var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);

    isUploaded = response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;

    return isUploaded;
}
```

Comment: Your answer really does not address the initial question regarding createfeeddocument.  To be able to process an uploaded file you need to create the documentId and the OP, like my situation was having issues.  Mine is accessed denied though when I use the same authorization for ORDERS it works.  Can you provide more code to show how you got a valida documentId from the create?  Also, what url did you use?